# Does mutation observers support iframe documents when added to the main html document?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, mutation-observers

I have not been able to get the mutation observers to work with documents with in an iframe. My main document contains multiple iframes with the same origin as the main document. I have added the mutation observer on the main document but the mutation observer does not fire when there is a dom change in the document with in the iframe. It fires when I add mutation observer to each and every document explicitly for every iframe in the main document.

Hence I want to know can the mutation observer monitor the changes made to the dom of the document with an iframe when the mutation observer is added to the main html document which hosts the iframe? Please help

Comment: iframe has a different  `document` in `iframe.contentDocument` so naturally the changes aren't propagated.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. So changes in the iframe document are never captured unless we explicitly attach a mutation observer to it.

Answer (score 1):

MutationObserver is linked only to the parent document so any changes inside of the iframe would not be captured.

if you have iframe information add the event listeners to each of the iframes or just look for all the children in the main document and event listeners to them.

I'm using this from a browser extension so all I had to was add
`"all_frames" : true`
inside the content scripts and this take care of adding the complete script tag so the events listeners will be added here as well